# Is it possible to use Core Location / GPS without any internet connection / disabled cellular network?

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I need to capture the GPS **coordinates** (no reverse geocoding, names, etc) in regions where there is no internet such as on a sailing boat or in the Sahara desert, so that you just get the latitude and longitude of where you are.

Does Core Location support that and falls back to GPS-only (no cell triangulation or WiFi location mapping)?

I think it does, but just want to be sure.

Comment: At first I was inclined to say no but when I honestly look at it I wonder if it's a separate component... another question I would have would be, "If so, would it charge the user anything depending on their data plan". Can you edit that in?

+1 for good question.

Comment: (I always assumed the "GPS" was just triangulation of cell towers but who knows)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw No, GPS doesn't have to do anything with cell tower triangulation. It's based on satellite + clock signals. But Core Location makes use of many different technologies to increase accuracy. GPS itself is slow and less accurate, depending on where you are. And it doesn't work in a garage. or when you're in a building. So by combining GPS with cell triangulation and WiFi networks to coordinate mapping they achieve better accuracy in certain tricky situations and also get the location much faster than plain vanilla GPS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some iOS devices have a real GPS chip allowing you to get location data even with no Internet connection. I believe the last few iPhones all have GPS. Some of the iPad models have GPS. I don't believe any of the iPod touch models have GPS.

Obviously without Internet you can't show any map data unless it is part of the app, but the app will be able to record real location data.

Also, without Internet, the GPS may take longer to get an initial position. The devices with GPS have what is called "assisted GPS". This means Cellular and/or WiFi triangulation is used to help get an initial position fix quicker that without.

Devices without GPS use cellular and/or WiFi triangulation to get estimated location data which is far less accurate than devices with GPS.

Comment: All iPhones have a GPS chip, so do all iPads that have cellular data (Wifi only iPads do not have GPS chip).  Data connection does speed up the acquisition time by providing an initial fix but is also used to download satellite ephemeris which is a lot faster than downloading it from the satellites themselves.

Comment: @progrmr +1. To be more precise, I believe that the original iPhone did not have GPS, but all of the other models do. But for all practical purposes, you are correct.

Comment: @progrmr: I like your point but can you please provide some link substantiating your point.

Comment: My `iPad mini 1st generation` sometimes shows me my location even I am not connected to the internet. Why it happens, since it doesn't have GPS, assisted GPS, GLONASS, and even cellular?

Answer (score 9):

The list of devices that allow you get location without wifi:

> **iPad + cellular**  *(assisted GPS)*
>   **iPad2 + cellular** *(assisted GPS)*
>   **iPad3 + cellular** *(assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPad4 + cellular** *(assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPad Air + cellular**  *(assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPad Air 2** *(iBeacon)*
>   **iPad Air 2 + cellular** *(assisted GPS + GLONASS + iBeacon)*
>
> **iPad Mini + cellular** *(assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPad Mini 2 + cellular**  *(assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPad Mini 3**  *(iBeacon)*
>   **iPad Mini 3 + cellular**  *(assisted GPS + GLONASS + iBeacon)*
>
> **iPhone 3G**  *(GPS + assisted GPS)*
>   **iPhone 3GS**  *(GPS + assisted GPS)*
>   **iPhone 4**  *(GPS + assisted GPS)*
>   **iPhone 4S**  *(GPS + assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPhone 5**  *(GPS + assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPhone 5C**  *(GPS + assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPhone 5S**  *(GPS + assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPhone 6**  *(GPS + assisted GPS + GLONASS)*
>   **iPhone 6 Plus**  *(GPS + assisted GPS + GLONASS)*

Devices that definitely **DO NOT** allow you get location without wifi.

> **iPhone  (1st generation)
>
>   iPod touch
>
>   iPad
>
>   iPad 2
>
>   iPad 3
>
>   iPad 4
>
>   iPad Air
>
>   iPad Mini
>
>   iPad Mini 2**