# Does my iOS device need internet (wifi/3g) to be GPS location updated?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gps, cllocationmanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use Core Location / GPS without any internet connection / disabled cellular network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326890/is-it-possible-to-use-core-location-gps-without-any-internet-connection-disa)

I need to know if my iOS device (iPhone, iPad, iPod touch) need internet to be upadted the current location or if the GPS will do standalone, I want to know because my iPad will not update the current location without any kind of internet, and I want to make sure if true or false, or probabbly bad GPS location or something.

Thanks, I'm just using CoreLocation without MKMapKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are halve right about the iPad, all devices that have 3G or 4G support will also have a full GPS receiver. Thus they do not an active internet connection to get a location.

On the other hand if your device has an active internet connection ti will able to give you a location quicker with triangulation of wifi and cell tower information.
You will first receive this location while the device tries to get a more accurate location via GPS.

Comment: Ok, I have just tested on an iPad 2 the location without internet or 3g and it will take some minutes to get updated the current location, but with that answer I don't know if my iPod touch will update without internet, but thanks I will try to install my test app in some iOS devices and test it... tyty

Comment: @rokimoki As you can see in the duplicate answer, no iPod touch has a real GPS.

Comment: ok @maddy ty ...EDIT: wich location will be more exactly with GPS or triangulation?

Comment: GPS, will be more exact. The triangulation is really rough and will more or less 800 meter in accuracy