# How to get the user location With out internet connectivity

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gps

I'm in need to get the user latitude and longitude, even the internet facility was not available in iOS.

**NOTE: NO internet, No Cellular Network and Cellular Service.**

Comment: Just send the user sms and tell him to reply with the current lat-lng

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326890/is-it-possible-to-use-core-location-gps-without-any-internet-connection-disa

Answer (score 0):

Add these variables in your @implementation:

```
CLLocationManager *manager;
CLGeocoder *geocoder;
```

In your viewDidLoad:

```
manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
manager.delegate = self;
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then add these methods:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    geolocerror = YES;
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat: %.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long: %.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add CoreLocation in your framework.

Comment: can you please read the ques. again?

Comment: @iTroyd23 CLLocation can return results without Internet connectivity in some cases.

Comment: @iTroyd23 what do you mean all cases. What have you tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [corelocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html)

> The Core Location framework lets you determine the current location or
>   heading associated with a device. The framework uses the available
>   hardware to determine the user’s position and heading. You use the
>   classes and protocols in this framework to configure and schedule the
>   delivery of location and heading events. You can also use it to define
>   geographic regions and monitor when the user crosses the boundaries of
>   those regions. In iOS, you can also define a region around a Bluetooth
>   beacon

.