# How to get the Current Latitude and Longitude without Internet connection in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Sometimes the user is not able to get the connection to the internet, so how to get the current location "Latitude and Longitude" of the user using GPS without internet connection ?

Comment: that is nothing you have to worry about, that is exactly what core-location is for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326890/is-it-possible-to-use-core-location-gps-without-any-internet-connection-disa

Comment: what I understand is that the same code work whether the device is connected to the internet or not , is that what you mean ?

Comment: I would assume so, yes. As long as *you* do not explicitly check for internet connection.

Comment: You can use the same code for getting the location with internet connection as without internet connection - I've done it in one of my apps, and the location is very accurate. It does, however, take up a lot of battery, so make sure you only fetch the location when needed